Why do I have to force a re-render to get any content showing?
Info
I am trying to implement a infinite scroll by also utilizing virtualizing in react. To do this I am using the packages @tanstack/react-query and @tanstack/react-virtual.
Problem
I have managed to get it working with the exception that I have to force a re-render to get any content to show up. I have narrowed the problem down to the scrollRef that useVirtualizer needs for the getScrollElement option when initializing.
To get the layout of my application to work correctly I have to move the container that gets the scrollRef to the parent component and set up the useRef in it to pass down as a prop to the child component so useVirtualizer can use it and set ref.current.
If I move the container with the scrollRef and useRef into the child component where useVirtualizer is called it works without having to force a re-render, but the layout in my application will not work correctly as it is a electron app that are using a "custom" scrollbar and not the window scrollbar.
Underneath is a simplified version of my code. I have also created a CodeSandbox where you can see the behavior in action.
CodeSandbox link (Click the force re-render button to get the content to show up)
Code
const Shows = ({
  scrollRef,
}: {
  scrollRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}) => {
  const [, setForceRerender] = useState(0);
  const { data, isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage } =
    useSuspenseInfiniteQuery({
      queryKey: ["shows"],
      queryFn: async ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          "https://demoapi.com?page=" + pageParam,
        );
        return data;
      },
      initialPageParam: 1,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) =>
        lastPage.page < lastPage.total_pages ? lastPage.page + 1 : undefined,
    });

  const shows = data ? data.pages.flatMap((page) => page.results) : [];
  const columnCount = 5;
  const rowCount = Math.ceil(shows.length / columnCount);
  const itemWidth = 166;
  const itemHeight = 248;

  const rowVirtualizer = useVirtualizer({
    count: hasNextPage ? rowCount + 1 : rowCount,
    getScrollElement: () => scrollRef.current,
    estimateSize: () => itemHeight,
    overscan: 1,
  });

  const columnVirtualizer = useVirtualizer({
    horizontal: true,
    count: columnCount,
    getScrollElement: () => scrollRef.current,
    estimateSize: () => itemWidth,
    overscan: 0,
  });

  const rowItems = rowVirtualizer.getVirtualItems();

  useEffect(() => {
    const [lastItem] = [...rowItems].reverse();

    if (!lastItem) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      (lastItem.index + 1) * columnCount >= shows.length - 1 &&
      hasNextPage &&
      !isFetchingNextPage
    ) {
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  }, [hasNextPage, fetchNextPage, shows.length, isFetchingNextPage, rowItems]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setForceRerender((prev) => prev + 1)}>
        Force rerender
      </button>
      <div
        style={{
          height: `${rowVirtualizer.getTotalSize()}px`,
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          userSelect: "none",
        }}
      >
        {rowVirtualizer.getVirtualItems().map((virtualRow) =>
          columnVirtualizer.getVirtualItems().map((virtualColumn) => {
            const isLoaderRow =
              virtualRow.index > Math.ceil(shows.length / 5) - 1;

            const index = virtualColumn.index + virtualRow.index * columnCount;
            const show = shows[index];

            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  width: `${virtualColumn.size}px`,
                  height: `${virtualRow.size}px`,
                  transform: `translateX(${virtualColumn.start}px) translateY(${virtualRow.start}px)`,
                }}
              >
                {!isLoaderRow && show && (
                  <div key={index} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "232px",
                        width: "150px",
                        objectFit: "fill",
                      }}
                      src={`${
                        show.poster_path
                          ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${show.poster_path}`
                          : "https://via.placeholder.com/185x278?text=Image+missing"
                      }`}
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          }),
        )}
      </div>
      {shows.length === 0 && (
        <div className="flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
          No shows to discover that matches your filters
        </div>
      )}
      {!hasNextPage && shows.length > 0 && (
        <div className="mt-2 flex justify-center">
          No more shows to discover
        </div>
      )}
      {isFetchingNextPage && (
        <div className="flex items-center">Loading next page...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading in app.tsx...</div>}>
      <div
        style={{
          height: "500px",
          overflow: "auto",
        }}
        ref={scrollRef}
      >
        <Shows scrollRef={scrollRef} />
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
}


After posting the question on the TanStack discord I got the answer.
If you store the ref in state with useState instead of using useRef it works correctly.
const [scrollRef, setScrollRef] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

<div ref={scrollRef}>...</div>

Then change the uses of the ref from scrollRef.current to just scrollRef
